# Change navigation icon

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this below navigation in my page :

```
<ul class="fa-ul" id="filter">
    <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-folder-o"></i><a href="{{route('fotoindex')}}">Semua Foto</a></li>
    @forelse($albums as $al)
    <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-folder-o"></i><a href="{{route('fotofilter', $al->slug)}}" name="album">{{$al->nama}}</a></li>
    @empty
    @endforelse
</ul>
```

I've managed to add  `active` class to the `a` element when the url in the given `a` element is opened in the browser with below code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        var path = window.location.href;
        $('#filter li a').each(function() {
            if (this.href === path) {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }});
    });
</script>
```

And now I want to know how to change the `i` element icon class as well ? let's say if the url is opened I want to change the icon class from `fa-li fa fa-folder-o` to `fa-li fa fa-folder-open-o`

That's all and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#filter li a').each(function() {
  if (this.href === path) {
    $(this).siblings('i').removeClass("fa-folder-o").addClass("fa-folder-open-o active");
  }
});
```